# Total flow of water in a pipe

Tags: calculus

The flow of water in a pipe is faster in the middle than near the outside. 
For a 2 cm diameter pipe, given that the velocity of the water as a function of 
distance from the center of the pipe is
$$v(r) = \frac {1-r^2}{\mathrm{cm}^2} \cdot 1.48 \mathrm m/\mathrm s.$$

Determine the total flow in the pipe in liters/second.

[image: Picture of situation]

What I've tried: Find total flow of water if uniform flow, i.e. if all water in pipe was flowing at a rate of 1.48 m/s.

$$(1.48 \mathrm m/\mathrm s) \pi (0.01\mathrm{cm})^2 \xrightarrow{\text{convert to liters/sec}} \approx 0.46 \text{liters}/\text{sec}.$$

Then multiply that by $\frac 2 3$ (integrate $1-x^2$ from -1 to 1) = 0.309 liters/sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a cross-section of the pipe. We calculate the amount of water that flows through it per second.

The amount that flows through the segment that goes from radius $r$ to radius $r+dr$ is the area of that segment, which is approximately $2\pi r\,dr$, times the rate $(148)(1-r^2)$.

"Add up" (integrate) from $r=0$ to $r=1$. We get
$$\int_0^1 (2\pi r)(148)(1-r^2)\,dr$$
cubic centimetres per second. Integrate, and divide by $1000$ to change from cubic cm to litres.